Install software on User1 and use it on User2
Newbie here. I am managing an Ubuntu workstation used by several people. Each user has their own account and has done whatever needed to use the machine (installing libraries, tools and so on). Now, I need to install a very intricate tool (a large collection of C and Fortran programs), lots of dependencies and libraries that should not be changed in the future to avoid problems.
If I create a new user, then I install my code in this user, Is there a way to make this code visible and executable by other users? I basically need the dependencies to be frozen somewhere that no-one can touch.
As required by @Bodo:
First I need to install the following dependencies with the package manager: sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin libmpich-dev libopenmpi-dev gcc g++ gfortran subversion libcurl4-openssl-dev wget make m4 git liburi-perl libxml2-dev.
Then I have to install zlib and hdf5, NetCDF-c and NetCDF-Fortran (in this order). These are prerequisites, and I need these to be untouchable by other processes, since the installation of NetCDF-c and NetCDF-Fortran must be done in a specific order, compiler must be the same and the options must be the same for both compilations. Thus, I prefer to download them somewhere in the home, compile them there and keep them there, rather than install them in the /lib folder that could be accessed also by python installation afterwards.
Finally I need to install XIOS-trunk and XIOS-2.5, and the two ocean models NEMO and CROCO that will depend directly on Xios, Hdf5 and netcdf-C and Fortran versions in their makefile. None of these 4 codes are shipped with a package manager or have an installation GUI. They are folders of source files to be compiled. These 4 are the programs I want to be able to run and access from other users, not the first list of dependencies
@terdon I do have root access

Do you have root access to this system?

Normally, software is installed as root for all users. I think you should tell more details in your question about the software you want to install.

@Bodo answered in original post

@Kimala so, install that software using the standard tools (apt-get/apt or the "software" GUI) and it's installed for everyone. Does that not work?

XIOS (both versions), NEMO and CROCO are not shipped with any apt or GUI. They are directories full of .F90 files to compile

Please tell us whether you have root access. That is the single most important point we need to know.

Yes I do @terdon

And all of these are packages in the repository? openmpi-bin libmpich-dev libopenmpi-dev gcc g++ gfortran subversion libcurl4-openssl-dev wget make m4 git liburi-perl libxml2-dev zlib hdf5 are all packages, right? Are NetCDF-c and NetCDF-Fortran available as deb files as well?

I can install openmpi-bin libmpich-dev libopenmpi-dev gcc g++ gfortran subversion libcurl4-openssl-dev wget make m4 git liburi-perl libxml2-dev with sudo apt-get install for sure. About zlib and hdf5 I'm not sure, I usually download the binaries and install them in my home. Netcdf-c and Netcdf-Fortran are as well binaries downloaded and installed in my home since they must be compiled with the same compiler and options and usually are really tricky to install.

Is it this: https://forge.ipsl.jussieu.fr/ioserver/browser/XIOS3/trunk/make_xios ? Maybe you can create something like /usr/local/xios and use option --build-path to build it there. You might have to temporarily grand write access there for the user that will run the build. Maybe there are similar options for the other SW.

This is somewhat of a tangent, but you might consider creating something like a Docker container image with these things.  That'd enable you to restrict the library versions, etc within the container without putting those requirements on the host itself.

For anything that is available as a package in your repositories, simply install with
sudo apt install package1 package2 ... packageN

All users will have access to what the packages install, and cannot change them without root access.
If you also need to install specific binaries, the details depend on how these are distributed. If they come as precompiled binaries and simply need to be copied somewhere, then copy them to /usr/local/bin. You could use any directory that is in your user's PATH variable, but /usr/local/bin is the normal location for such binaries. See the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy:

The /usr/local hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when
installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being
overwritten when the system software is updated. It may be used for
programs and data that are shareable amongst a group of hosts, but not
found in /usr.
Locally installed software must be placed within /usr/local rather
than /usr unless it is being installed to replace or upgrade software
in /usr.

If you download source code and compile it yourself, it will probably come with an install script. Usually, the proceeedure is:

Extract the files from the source tarball. Something like tar xvzf someDomeCode.tar.gz

cd into the directory the command above created where the files will be and run ./configure.

Run make to compile.

Run sudo make install to install the various bits and pieces to the right place (the configure script above should have determined what the right place is).


Now, again, the tools should be available to all users.

I am guessing that for zlib and hdf5, you want to install them so that other tools can be compiled using them, so you want the -dev versions of the packages:
sudo apt install zlib1g-dev libhdf5-dev


You might also want to place a hold on upgrading these packages using something like apt-mark hold zlib1g-dev to make it more difficult for other users with sudo rights to upgrade to a conflicting version.
